# How to keep "Add" button fixed at the top when clicked to add a new input from field in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, onclick

I have a component in React where when the "Add" button is clicked, new form fields are created. However, when I click on the add button, the new form fields are added at the top of the add button instead of below it.

I need the add button to be fixed at the top and the new form fields created to stack at the top of the other existing form fields. I would like to know what I need to change on my code to achieve this.

[image]

```
  function DynamicFormFields() {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ name: "", quantity: "" }]);

  // handle input change
  const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setInputList(list);
  };

  // handle click event of the Remove button
  const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    const list = [...inputList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setInputList(list);
  };

  // handle click event of the Add button
  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setInputList([{ name: "", quantity: "" }, ...inputList]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="DynamicFormFields">
        <h3>
          <p>Dynamic Form</p>
        </h3>

        {inputList.map((x, i) => {
          // x -> element, i -> index
          return (
            <div className="box">
              <div className="btn-box">
                {inputList.length - 1 === i && (
                  <button onClick={handleAddClick}>Add</button>
                )}
              </div>
              <input
                name="name"
                placeholder="Name"
                value={x.name}
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
              />
              <input
                type="number"
                name="quantity"
                // className="ml10"
                min="1"
                max="12"
              ></input>
              {inputList.length !== 1 && (
                <button className="mr10" onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}>
                  Remove
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I would put the form fields in one div and the button in a separate one. If you have any problems with positioning you could also look at css position:relative and positions:absolute. Hope that helps

Comment: Hello! I did try to put the forms and the button in separate div elements but the add button still remains at the end of the forms. Even when I add css style to position the button at the top, whenever a new row of forms is added, the button moves down as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure I completely understand what you want but I made some changes real quick (may contain mistakes). Is this what you're trying to do? Also I would suggest making your input items into small sub components, that may help you see the overall picture more clearly.

```
function DynamicFormFields() {
const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ name: "", quantity: "" }]);

// handle input change
const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setInputList(list);
};

// handle click event of the Remove button
const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    const list = [...inputList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setInputList(list);
};

// handle click event of the Add button
const handleAddClick = () => {
    setInputList([{ name: "", quantity: "" }, ...inputList]);
};

return (
    <>
    <div className="DynamicFormFields">
        <h3>
        <p>Dynamic Form</p>
        </h3>
        <div className="box">
        <div className="btn-box">
            <button onClick={handleAddClick}>Add</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            {inputList.map((x, i) => {
            // x -> element, i -> index
            return (
                <div>
                <input
                    name="name"
                    placeholder="Name"
                    value={x.name}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                />
                <input
                    type="number"
                    name="quantity"
                    // className="ml10"
                    min="1"
                    max="12"
                ></input>
                {inputList.length !== 1 && (
                    <button
                    className="mr10"
                    onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}
                    >
                    Remove
                    </button>
                )}
                </div>
            );
            })}
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </>
);
}
```

The main changes here is that I put the button outside of the loop as it shouldn't be dependent on your other input items, as I understand it. I also wrapped your inputs inside another div to completely separate the button and the inputs. Make sure only what needs to be updated gets updated so you don't get unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I tried this and it works perfectly. Thank you so much. I'll also do your recommendation to have separate components for the form elements.